# How can I call a point in the future of a time series that I would like to forecast?

Tags: machine-learning, forecasting, lstm

I'm a beginner in time series forecasting and I'm not sure if I understood correctly the meaning of forecast horizon. I was considering horizons as points in the future for which we would like to predict a value. For example, a horizon of 30 days would, in my approach, means that we want to predict the 30th value of a time series. And I'm not interested in knowing the other points before this one. But in some works, forecast horizons are considered as the set of points in the future that we want to predict. In this case, a horizon of 30 days means that we want to predict the values of the 30 days in the future.

It seems that what literature calls horizon is the second alternative. There is a name for the first one?

Bst regards.